# Stripped JSP tags (c:elements)

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jsp-tags

Good morning all,

I am a Junior Developer and I have been hired on to stream-line the HTML and CSS code for several projects, integrating my HTML and CSS into existing JSPs within Eclipse STS IDE.

Ultimately, I am trying to reduce the code so that it is much cleaner, better organized, and specificity is on the same level. I do this using A-BEM documentation.

Now, when I integrate into the JSPs, I am positive that I am working around any  tags and EL statments, careful to maintain any code that would break the project if it were otherwise removed.

Everything works fine when it is tested on my machine.

The issue occurs when I commit my code; my lead developer is finding that I have "deleted all of the JSP tags". And I know for a fact that I have not.

I have a feeling that something is going wrong during the commit process, but I am not entirely sure what the issue could be.

Here is an example of the code that I am given to work with:

```
<!-- OLD FOOTER -->
<div class="white_bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top_footer">
            <ul>
                <li class="left">
                    <img src="/resources/assets/images/Placeholder text.png" 
                    class="top_footer_logo"/>
                    <hr class="no_border"/>
                    Placeholder text.
                </li>
                <li class="middle">
                    <br/>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${isLoggedIn}">                           
                            <a href="/booking/BookStepOne"> <i class="fa fa-
                            calendar-plus-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Book a 
                            Space </a> 
                        </c:when>                       
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <a href="/Login"> <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-
                            hidden="true"></i> Log In </a>
                            <br/>
                            <a href="/Register"> <i class="fa fa-user-plus" 
                            aria-hidden="true"></i> Register </a>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="/ContactUs"> <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-
                    hidden="true"></i> Contact Us </a>
                    <br/>
                    Hours:<br/> Mon - Fri: 8:30 am - 4:30 pm                        
                </li>
                <li class="right">
                    <br/>
                    Placeholder text.
                    <br/>
                    Placeholder text.                       
                    <br/>
                    San Francisco, CA 94111
                    <br/>
                    <a href="placeholdertext" 
                    target="_blank"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                        Get Directions 
                    </a>                                
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
        &copy;<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" />  <a 
        href="http://www.Placeholdertext.com/"> Tarkett NA </a>, All Rights 
        Reserved.
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is an example of my approach:

```
<!-- NEW FOOTER -->
<section class="o-footer__topSection -whiteBg">
  <div class="m-topFooter__left">
    <div class="m-logoContain">
        <img src="/resources/assets/images/placeholdertext.png" class="a-
        freelLogo"/>
    </div>
    <p class="a-copy">placeholdertext.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="m-topFooter__mid">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${isLoggedIn}">                           
            <a href="/booking/BookStepOne"> <i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o" 
            aria-hidden="true"></i> Book a Space </a> 
        </c:when>                       
        <c:otherwise>
            <a href="/Login" class="a-botNavLink"> <i class="fa fa-sign-in" 
            aria-hidden="true"></i> Log In </a>
            <a href="/Register" class="a-botNavLink"> <i class="fa fa-user-
            plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register </a>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <a href="/ContactUs" class="a-botNavLink"> <i class="fa fa-envelope" 
    aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact Us </a>
    <p class="a-copy">Hours:<br/> Mon - Fri: 8:30 am - 4:30 pm
  </div>
  <div class="m-topFooter__right">
    <p class="a-copy">placeholdertext</p>
    <p class="a-copy">placeholdertext</p>
    <p class="a-copy">placeholdertext</p>
    <a href="placeholdertext" class="a-botNavLink" 
    target="_blank"> 
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Get Directions 
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="o-footer__botSection -blackBg">
  <div class="m-contain">
    <jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
    &copy;<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" />  <a 
    href="placeholdertext"> Tarkett NA </a>, All Rights Reserved.
  </div>
</section>
```

Has anyone ever run into this issue? If so, how might this be resolved?

I am using Eclipse STS, Tomcat 8.0 Servers, and SVN version control.

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: What dos _deleted all of the JSP tags_ mean?  What does the committed file look like?

Comment: This I am unable to obtain. We had to revert all the files in order to complete the project on time. I was left perplexed because I had been positive that my approach had been correct. When he said "deleted all of the JSP tags", he was talking about all of the c:tags (ie. c:out, c:choose, c:forEach), these sorts of things. I wish I could provide more information for you, but this was a question that I've been pondering for the past few days and, again, I'm perplexed.

Comment: As an experiment, copy the file to a new name, make the changes, and commit.  Use Eclipse's Compare With... to see if the file in the repo changed.  Or just browse the repo directly.

Comment: Alright, after viewing what's in the repository, I've found that all of the code would come across exactly as I had written it, so perhaps this is not the issue? My next thought would be that working on the project simultaneously caused the issue. But then this would be resolved by merge conflicts, right? At any rate, I appreciate the help!